# Как менять цвет текста при выборе обьекта из списка

Tags: javascript, yii2

Сам Код

```
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h3><span style="color:#e32636">ТАРИФ</span></h3>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'tarif')->dropDownList(
            $model->car_tarif,
            [
                'prompt'=>'Бесплатно',
                'style' => 'width:130px;',
            ]
        )->label(false) ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <!--<li>Спецразмещение: <b class="gold gold_count">нет</b></li>-->
            <li>Поднятие в ТОП: <b class="gold gold_count">нет</b></li>
            <li>Выделение цветом: <b class="gold gold_count">нет</b></li>
        </div>
        <script>
            $("select#car-tarif").change(function() {
              $(".gold_count").html( $("select#car-tarif option:selected").val() == 1 ? '<span style="color:green">На 1 день</span>' : $("select#car-tarif option:selected").text() );
              $(".gold_cost_coutn").html( $("select#car-tarif").val() == 1 ? $("select#car-tarif option:selected").text().toLowerCase() : "за " + $("select#car-tarif").val()*<?= Car::COURS ?> + " руб.");
            });
        </script>

        <hr />
    </div>
```

Надо чтобы первый выбор т.е. (Нет) было красным, в стилях указал, а теперь все тарифы стали красными, нашел выход такой

```
<script>
            $("select#car-tarif").change(function() {
              $(".gold_count").html( $("select#car-tarif option:selected").val() == 1 ? '<span style="color:green">На 1 день</span>' : $("select#car-tarif option:selected").text() );
              $(".gold_cost_coutn").html( $("select#car-tarif").val() == 1 ? $("select#car-tarif option:selected").text().toLowerCase() : "за " + $("select#car-tarif").val()*<?= Car::COURS ?> + " руб.");
            });
        </script>
```

Но придется тогда писать каждый раз когда появляется новый тариф, можно  сделать так

```
$(".gold_count").html( $("select#car-tarif option:selected").val() >= 1 ?
```

Но тогда все автоматически выдает "На 1 день"

```
'<span style="color:green">На 1 день</span>'
```

Что тут надо прописать чтобы он брал название автоматически? т.к. текст = названию тарифа

Answer (score 1):

CSS (первый тариф делает красным):

```
div.form-group li:first-child b {
   color: red;
}
```